# Divide X by Y, return number of items in last, partial set

Tags: c#, math

I'm probably missing something really simple, but I'm trying to figure out how to calculate what's left over after I divide X by Y. I don't mean the remainder, I mean, e.g. if I divide 100 by 7 => 6 groups of 15 + one group of 10, how do I get 10?

I don't have code to show because I have no idea where start. X and Y are both integers.

Comment: I think nobody really gets what you are trying to calculate. What you described is not really a division.

Comment: Does the modulo operator not giving what you want? If yes then explain it more what you want and also add some code which you have tried?

Comment: Is what you want like this:  100 split into 7 parts: 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, (15 - 5)?
It isn't precisely division, but, theoretically could be calculated...

You could try doing   (100 % (7 - 1))...
Otherwise seen as:      (X % (Y - 1)) ? (X % (Y - 1)) : (X / Y)

Comment: Nikhil, your edit completely changed the question, I think the op is trying to find a way to divide a number into uneven ammounts.  (7 would leave a remainder) OP, why does this give 6 groups of 15 and one of 10 and not (for example) 6 groups of 16 and one of 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not as simple as just using modulus. The fiddly bit is calculating your initial group size from the number of groups.

Try this:

```
int population = 100;
int numberOfGroups = 7;
int groupSize = (population + numberOfGroups - 1)/numberOfGroups;

Console.WriteLine(groupSize);

int remainder = population%groupSize;

Console.WriteLine(remainder);
```

Answer (score 0):

`I don't mean the remainder`

Yes you mean remainder.

If you divide 100 by 15, you get 6 as quotient and 10 as remainder.

use Modulus operator like

```
int remainder = 100 % 15; // This will return 6

int quotient = 100/15;  // This will return 10
```

Comment: But the OP is starting with 100 and 7.  You need to show how you got from that to 15 by doing Ceiling(100/7).

Answer (score 0):

It's a modulo operator, isntead of:

```
var result = x / y;
```

Try this:

```
var result = x % y;
```

EDIT. 
Ok You are very unclear but i think one of below solutions is what You are trying to avhieve.

S1. do this:

```
int x = 100/15;
int z = 15 * x;
int y = 100 - z; // and You got Your 10
```

S2. do this:

```
int x = 100/7;
if ( x * 7 != 100)
{
    int GroupSize = x+1;
    int rest = 100 - GroupSize;
}
```

Comment: @JuannStrauss:- Does the modulo operator not giving what you want?

Comment: "if I divide 100 by 7" - how You want to achive 10  ?

Comment: 100 / gives (6 * 15) + (1 * 10). How do I get 10?

Comment: @JuannStrauss it depends on how you determine it is 6*15 and so on, not for example (5 * 19) + (1 * 10)

Comment: @JuannStrauss  check my edit ... is this what You wanted ? Your question is very unclear

Comment: Sorry for that. I don't know what the proper English words are, so I tried to demonstrate. Look at the accepted answer.

Comment: It's working like my S2., i had this feeling that this is what You were looking for. Glad You found Your answer